# Build deb project failed

Tags: testing, compilation, package, deb, dpkg

I am trying to compile a deb project and it failed on the testing. Is there a way to skip the test? I already tried the option DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS=nocheck debuild -us -uc but the project still trying to make a test.
As I know it should be an option inside debian/rules to skip it. Can you help me what I have to add to this file?
Thanks